# Extract information from a log file using powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0, logfiles, event-viewer

Hi I am new to the language of powershell s i though about playing around with it. I am trying to extract information out of a log file (the file belongs to a program called event viewer). I need to use the information under Boot Duration.
Could somebody guide me a little bit? 
It will be greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Just to give some more information:
The purpose of my script will be to measure the time taken for the box to boot up. Also the log file that i am trying to extract the info out of it does not open with notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Logs are always the same. Not sure if you are going to monitor boot log of windows or linux or what.. but will try to answer.
If you edit your question and add info on the operating system and an example of relevant lines of boot log file I can provide you with some powershell code.

In general you should do:

- Identify how to manually see boot time in log file. For example
  probably it will have a starting boot time and a finished boot time.
  Something similar to this.

> [2012-06-08 12:00:04] starting boot
>
> lot of log entries
>
> [2012-06-08 12:00:34] finished boot

- Once you know how to do it manually, you have to convince powershell to do it for you. You can use regular expressions to look for the pattern of dates. In my example look for lines that contains "starting boot" and then parse it to load date.

Here you have an useful link on powershell and regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html